# Запрет ввода в textEdit только русских символов

Tags: delphi, текст, vcl

Почему-то данный код не блокирует ввод русских (кириллических) символов

```
procedure Tf_main.KeyPress_ENG(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key in ['А'..'я']) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так попробовать:

```
begin
  if (Key >= 'А') and (Key <= 'я') then
    Key := #0;
end;
```